# Trouble running mc_replicate on Windows

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am having some trouble running *mc_replicate* (from the mcreplicate library) on Windows (10). I am using R v. 4.1.1 on a machine with 8 cores. When I try to execute this code:

```
x1 <- mc_replicate(10000, runRandomLot(), mc.cores = 8,
                    envir = environment(), varlist = "runRandomLot",
                    packages = c("dplyr","magrittr"))
```

I get this error:

```
Running parallel code on Windows: a parallel socket cluster will be used.

Variables and packages needed for code execution must be explicitely specified.

See the help file for more information and current defaults.


Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) (ImplantGapRA.R#76): 8 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "%>%"
```

The error suggests that the *magrittr* package is not being passed, but the docs do not provide clear guidance on how to pass the packages (if that's what the problem is). Any guidance on how to correct my call to mc_replicate would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't really use this package at all on Windows; multicore uses forking which isn't a Windows OS concept. Stick to regular parallel, foreach, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes, I'd expect specifying `packages = "magrittr"` would solve this, but I have zero experience with the [**mcreplicate**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mcreplicate).  Second, and more importantly, I peeked at the [code](https://github.com/cran/mcreplicate/blob/0.1.2/R/mcreplicate.R) for `mcreplicate::mc_replicate()` and what's worrying is that it does not set up proper parallel random number generation (RNG), which means the results you get from the parallel workers might be correlated although you'd expect a `replicate()` call to give you proper random numbers.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author).  If you have working code using **base**'s `replicate()`, I'd recommend that you replace it as-is with [`future_replicate()`](https://future.apply.futureverse.org/reference/future_lapply.html) of the [**future.apply**](https://future.apply.futureverse.org/) package for parallelization.  Something like:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession, workers = 8)  ## Parallelize on 8 local workers

x1 <- future_replicate(10000, runRandomLot())
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you, HenrikB. This is a beautiful solution! I appreciate you taking the time to peek under the hood of mc_replicate and providing your insight. A question for you on a warning message from a run of future_replicate. I get 8 messages similar to this: "Warning in .Internal(rawConnection(deparse(substitute(object)), object,  :
  closing unused connection 19 (<-Thinkpad-P15:11655)". Is there anything that I can do to address the warning? Kind regards. David.

Comment: Thank you and nema problema.  For those warnings, which I never seen before but should also not be there, could you please bring this up on <https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions>?  Please try to do it using a minimal reproducible example that others can run as well.